# Turn text input into image

Tags: jquery, input, attr

I have an input field where a user could insert keywords, separated by commas. I'd like to generate an image with an src that is that keyword, with a default file extension of .png. The images are named based on anticipated keywords, so an image file isn't being created here.

So, for example, a list:

[puppy, kitty, balloon, cookie]

Once a keyword that has an image is typed, a little icon for that thing pops up in another place in the hierarchy.

I'm already familiar enough with jquery to do a similar trick, but it's the comma separated list part that i'm unsure how to tackle. I could take the value attribute of the input field, then set the image's src to that value, as a variable. But how to capture only what's between commas is the main question. (The space after a comma would be irrelevant)

Comment: I did not quite get the scenario... so, what will happen once a key in the words `balloon, cookie` in the input text? will it pop balloon image? cookie image? both? or none?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a split/trim/map:

```
var words = [];
jQuery.each(jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input").val()).split(","), function(index, value){ words.push(jQuery.trim(value));
});
```

That would give you an array of words nicely trimmed.

Comment: @TheSuperTramp - the second one. The first will only remove the whitespace surrounding the entire input string. The second one is the needed on, since it will trim the first and last words of the input string.

Comment: @Femi Thanks for the indepth answer, so would: $('img').attr("src", words+'.png'); flesh out the rest of the effect i'm looking for? (taking the word and using it as an src, adding the necessary extension.)

Comment: Well, `words` will be an array: you'd want something like `$('img').attr("src", words[0]+'.png');` to get an image for the first word, all the way up to `$('img').attr("src", words[words.length-1]+'.png');` to get the image for the last word.

Comment: @Femi - in which case i'd want to use a loop to render each string in the array?

Comment: The loop is right: I was assuming you could have multiple words.